# Django dynamic links using multiple fields

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a url set up dynamically for a project using:

```
path('project/<int:pk>', ProjectView.as_view(), name='project')
```

How can I make this so I can use two parameters, something like this:

```
path('project/<int:pk>/<int:category', ProjectView.as_view(), name='project')
```

So I need to set up links to each category, so the user will see only the updates from Project A category 1 of 7.

Comment: Exactly the same way, but you forgot a closing bracket `>`.

Answer (score 1):

If `ProductView` is a `DetailView`, you need to alter the `get_queryset` a bit, like:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class ProductView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template = 'some_template.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            category__id=self.kwargs['category']
        )
```

Here we thus will filter the queryset first by `'category'`, and the boilerplate code of the `DetailView` will then filter by the primary key `pk`.

In your templates, you can generate urls, with:

```
{% url 'project' pk=some_pk category=some_category_id %}
```

or if you for example redirect:

```
     return redirect('project', pk=some_pk, category=some_category_id)
```

Comment: Hmm, this gives me the following error: "get_queryset() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" what am I passing that I wasn't before?

Comment: @iFucntion: sorry I forgot the `self`.

Comment: Thank you, I have realized I have a bigger problem, I was trying to use data from two different models, so unfortunately, again, no joy. PK refers to the Project model and category is a foreign key to Update model from another table.